# Change event in radio in native javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my selectbox to be enabled when the radio button is checked. My code works for this. But if I choose other option. My selectbox didn't change into disabled.

Here's my code:
HTML

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="first">
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Ganjil - Genap 2D</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Besar - Kecil 2D</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Tengah - Tepih 2D</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Kombinasi 2D</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>SHIO</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Over / Under</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input class="jitu" name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Colok Jitu</p>
      <select disabled>
        <option>As</option>
        <option>Kop</option>
        <option>Kepala</option>
        <option>Ekor</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>4D</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Cari Data">
</div>
```

For Javascript

```
var jitu = document.getElementsByClassName('jitu');

for(var i = 0; i < jitu.length; i++){
    jitu[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        (this.checked) ? this.parentNode.children[2].disabled = false : this.parentNode.children[2].disabled = true;
    });
}
```

Thanks for those who will help. Cheers!

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c3a2q3n8/

Comment: Hayley,other option in your post means other radio buttons??

Comment: @NagaSaiA  I just want to check if the radio is checked or not. I thought that if the button is deselect. It will also call the change event. But it doesn't,

Answer (score 0):

You should give each input add a class name 'jitu'

Comment: Yeah. That's the last option. It should make my project slow. I want to check the radio if is selected or not. I want the (blur) - like event. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your html is not dynamically generated then you can slightly modify your html like this

Note that I have added a `onclick` function for each radio input and a unique value attribute.

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="first">
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="1">
            <p>
                Ganjil - Genap 2D</p>
        </label>
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="2">
            <p>
                Besar - Kecil 2D</p>
        </label>
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="3">
            <p>
                Tengah - Tepih 2D</p>
        </label>
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="4">
            <p>
                Kombinasi 2D</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="5">
            <p>
                SHIO</p>
        </label>
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="6">
            <p>
                Over / Under</p>
        </label>
        <label class="group">
            <input class="jitu" name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="7">
            <p>
                Colok Jitu</p>
            <select disabled id="jitusl">
                <option>As</option>
                <option>Kop</option>
                <option>Kepala</option>
                <option>Ekor</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label class="group">
            <input name="sg-a" type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="8">
            <p>
                4D</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Cari Data">
</div>
```

Now you have to place this `handleClick()` in js and check for specific value to either enable/disable it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function handleClick(myRadio) {
            alert('New value: ' + myRadio.value);
            if (myRadio.value === "7") {
                document.getElementById('jitusl').disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('jitusl').disabled = true;
            }            
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a global variable (`currentSelect`) to track the current active select and used the `click` event rather than the `change` event since `change` fires at different times for different browsers.  I'm also attaching the event to all your radio buttons instead of just the one with the select otherwise it will not fire when a different radio is selected (and also in case you wanted to add more selects)

```
var currentSelect;

function setupClickHandlers() {
    var jitu = document.getElementsByName('sg-a');

    for(var i = 0; i < jitu.length; i++){
        jitu[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (currentSelect) {
               currentSelect.disabled = !currentSelect.parentNode.children[0].checked;
            }
            if (this.parentNode.children[2]) {
                currentSelect = this.parentNode.children[2]
                currentSelect.disabled = !this.checked;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you click on the other options, the trigger isn't fired because the focused item isn't the one that you wrote the function for.

You should make a function that is triggered on change of every option, beware of the radio button so it knows whether to disable or enable it.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var selectInput = document.getElementById('dropdownSelect');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var input = inputs[i];
    if(input.type!='radio') continue;
    input.addEventListener('change', function(){
        var isJitu = ( this.className && this.className.match(/jitu/) )? true : false;
        selectInput.disabled = !isJitu;
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="first">
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Ganjil - Genap 2D</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Besar - Kecil 2D</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Tengah - Tepih 2D</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Kombinasi 2D</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>SHIO</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Over / Under</p>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input class="jitu" name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>Colok Jitu</p>
      <select disabled  id="dropdownSelect">
        <option>As</option>
        <option>Kop</option>
        <option>Kepala</option>
        <option>Ekor</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label class="group">
      <input name="sg-a" type="radio">
      <p>4D</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Cari Data">
</div>
```